# Cannot GET /phpmyadmin after setting up phpmyadmin and reverse proxy in Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

I followed Digital Ocean's tutorials on setting up Nginx, PHP, and phpmyadmin.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

But I still can't access phpmyadmin with the address (my-ip-address/phpmyadmin) I set.

And I setup the reverse proxy for a node.js app listening on localhost:8010.

Here's the setup in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name "my ip address";

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8010/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; 
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
         }
```

}

Comment: Is `fastcgi` running?

Comment: @ErvalhouS Yes I created an info.php file using 'sudo nano /var/www/html/info.php' and wrote <?php phpinfo(); ?> . Then I'm able to access the php info on my server using the address 'my-ip-address/info.php'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're proxying all requests to http://localhost:8010 with this block:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8010/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

None of the requests can make it to phpmyadmin. Try commenting this block out or deleting it and it should work as you expect.

Comment: I set up the reverse proxy for a node.js app listening on localhost:8010. Should I change it?

Comment: Oh, in that case, you just need to add a new `location /phpmyadmin` block with a `root` pointing to your phpmyadmin install. Since now all requests are going to your node.js app by default.

Comment: Thank you. I've added the phpmyadmin block and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need a block specifically for your `location /phpmyadmin`. Since you have set a rule to redirect to you fastCGI only if explicit extension is `.php` on the `location ~ \.php$ {` block, the `/phpmyadmin` location gets processed as a request to your proxy application. You have to add this:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
   root /path/to/phpmyadmin;
   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code to access the phpmyadmin:

```
  location /phpmyadmin {
     root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

}
```